# How to remove back-round image - Einstein Analytics Dashboard?

Tags: einstein-analytics-dashboards

I have uploaded an image to be a back-round of a dashboard, [image]however, can't find a way to remove for the back-ground to be default (empty)?

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the JSON with Ctrl+E, and then at the end of your layout you will find 
"image" : { "your image"
}
juste remove it to have :
"image": {}